# How do I make children of conditional form disappear and clear when a different parent is chosen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Thanks for helping - I apologize ahead of time if my title was a bit confusing, Im having a hard time explaining the issue and even finding a solution.

Im trying to create a conditional form for a module that I'm currently building, but am paralyzed by my lack of true javascript knowledge.

*The code I'm currently working with can be found at:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/jgliesman/MQjf8/3/*
```

*What I would like the form to do can be found at:

```
http://form.jotform.us/form/22290232014135*
```

What Im trying to get the "mini code" to do is (like the Jotform)...

**Clear the drop down/input selection if you change the parent. Right now the "mini code" is not hiding the 'grand-children' of the main parent when you switch to another parent. The direct child disappears but the 'grand-child' remains**

**I would also like it to reset the drop down/input selection if its hidden because if you pull it back up the selected option is still apparent its just hidden.**

If you would like me to clarify anything please let me know, I really appreciate the help.

Thanks again,

Comment: when I tried to use it, the form you link to doesn't actually reset the column, it just hides/shows an entire form element (the "profession" drop-down).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MQjf8/4/

It does the same as @undifned suggested, but it also takes the reset into account.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#select1").change(function(){

            if ($(this).val() == "1" ) {
                $('#hide1 select').val('(choose one)'); // select default
                $("#hide1").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect

            } else {

                $("#hide1").slideUp("fast");    //Slide Up Effect
                $("#hide2").slideUp("fast");    //Slide Up Effect
            }
        });

        $("#select2").change(function(){

            if ($(this).val() == "1" ) {
                $('#hide2 select').val('(choose one)'); // select default
                $("#hide2").val('(choose one)').slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect

            } else {

                $("#hide2").slideUp("fast");    //Slide Up Effect

            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#select1").change(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == "1") {
                $("#hide1").slideDown("fast");     
            } else {   
                $("#hide1").slideUp("fast");    
                $("#hide2").slideUp("fast");
                $("#select2 option:first").prop('selected', true);
                $("#select3 option:first").prop('selected', true);                                
            }
        });    
        $("#select2").change(function(){    
            if ($(this).val() == "1") {    
                $("#hide2").slideDown("fast");   
            } else {    
                $("#hide2").slideUp("fast");       
            }
        });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MQjf8/15/)

Comment: Wow, thank you that was incredibly fast! The snippet defiantly cured the "hiding the grand-child element" issue but is there also a way to clear the info that might be saved in that option. For example if you look at the fiddle (which I just updated) If you answer the first 2 quesitons correctly to view the 3rd and select some bogus answer - then change the overall parent, and repeat the process, the grand-child will still have the same selected option as if it was never cleared to be fresh

Comment: That seemed to work on an an overall scale but I think PeterVR's even worked on the children too, which is a plus -- http://jsfiddle.net/MQjf8/4/

Comment: @JesseGliesman You can use the `prop` method wherever it's needed, i.e. in your second `if` statement.